# App reject with seller and company names associated with your app

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Currently my app rejected with this reason, I have submitted app with my client's name and permission to upload app in my account but apple guys are saying like this

> The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “App Name￼” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Is anyone have faced this issue ? Why i need to purchase account when i have already taken the authentication permission from my client and i have attached the document while submitting the app to App Store i have tried two times but faced same issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a programming question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 3):

> The reported PLA 1.2 guideline issue is in regards to the seller and company names associated with your app not reflect the name “COMPANY NAME” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

It would be appropriate for your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the COMPANY NAME brand.

If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the Contact Us page.

[Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73820)

Comment: they are saying i need to buy another account for my client